# API Error - Token is not the correct length

Tags: magento-2.1, rest-api

We have two Magento 2.1 stores, one store i can connect to the REST API fine the other i get "Token is not the correct length" which is being classed as a 400 error in Postman.

The API has been working fine and no work has been carried out on the site since it was last working.

Any help would be greatly appreciated into getting this working

Thanks